# No changes to file with python script until saved in notepad

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a script that removes blank lines and leading spaces from text files placed inside of a directory. This works, sort of. The issue I am having is the script only creates the expected output when I first open the file in notepad and then save it. No changes need to be made to the file, just the act of opening and saving the file allows this to work. If I do not open and save the file I end up with just a copy of the original, spaces and all.

I am using python 3 and windows 8.

```
import os
import glob
import re

def cleanLeadingWhiteSpace(inputSrc, outputDest):
    for line in inputSrc:
        cleanLine = (line.lstrip())
        if re.match(r'^\s*$', cleanLine):
            print ('blank line removed')
        outputDest.write(cleanLine)

for file in glob.glob('input\*.txt'):
    sourceFile = open (file,'r+')
    outputFileName = ('output' + file[5:])
    outputFile = open (outputFileName,'w+')
    print ('Output File: ',outputFileName)
    cleanLeadingWhiteSpace(sourceFile,outputFile)
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Did you close the file after the edit? `file.close()`

Comment: You're not closing the file object, so you're never writing to the disk just to the buffer. Call `outputFile.close()` at the end of your `for file in glob` loop

Comment: I added the    outputFile.close() to the end but the result is still the same. Thanks for pointing that out, I needed to do that regardless.

Comment: So you do produce an output file that's the same as the input file? diff -q input output reports that the files are identical? If that's the case, then line.lstrip() is not being executed somehow.

Comment: Running FC on the files reports no difference between the 2 files. This is baffling, why would a save on the file allow this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend refactoring your function to take filenames instead of file objects, but if you insist, do this instead:

```
import os, glob

def clean_leading_whitespace(src, dst):
    for line in src:
        cleaned = line.lstrip()
        if cleaned == "":
            print ('blank line removed')
            # matches an empty string, e.g. a blank line
        dst.write(cleaned)

for file in glob.glob('input\*.txt'):
    dst_name = 'output' + file[5:]
    with open(file, 'r+') as src, open(dst_name, 'w+') as dst:
        clean_leading_whitespace(src,dst)
        # Context manager makes sure your files are closed
    print("Output file: ", dst_name)
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam Smith, greatly appreciated. The issue persists and I am starting to think this is a windows file ownership/permission issue.